# Python Tk (Tkinter) not work transparency on ubuntu unity

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

This code in python 2.7.3 work in windows xp, not work in Ubuntu Unity. 
How make in ubuntu window transparency.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from Tkinter import Tk

window = Tk()
window.wm_attributes('-alpha',0.8)
window.geometry('500x500+200+211')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code works on my ubuntu,with gnome-shell.

Comment: But with Ubuntu Unity doesn't work

Comment: Transparency in ubuntu, exapmle https://www.dropbox.com/s/d57md9c0djql0u3/terminal-ubuntu.png ,but doesn't work python tk transparent window

Comment: pyqt4 - work, bug in python-tkinter ?

Comment: @wd5: [the tk docs](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm#M11) say that it should work only on Windows.

Comment: @wd5 This is a purely Tk issue, it has no relation to Python or Tkinter. The documentation linked earlier here is simply not up to date, for instance see http://wiki.tcl.tk/10515. Also note that at the bottom of this same page there is a quick notice about window managers in Xorg with compositing enabled. A more official and correct documentation is at http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M9, although that is for Tcl 8.6, the documentation for `-alpha` is basically a doc correction of that one present in the older version.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
from Tkinter import Tk

window = Tk()
window.wait_visibility(window)
window.wm_attributes('-alpha',0.8)
window.geometry('500x500+200+211')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that this create a blink (the window starts out fully visible), which isn't the most pleasant